# Is good idea use sun.misc.BASE64Decoder / sun.misc.BASE64Encoder?

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm using a webservice to send data between Android APP and a SOAP Webservice.
This Webservice, only accept serialized objects, and the only way to do this, is using a:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
```

This class allow to "encrypt" data in a single String and viceversa, but the question is:

**1.**- Is, for a production purposes, good idea?

**2.**- Exists other ways to do the same and more efficiently?

Thanks for all responses and good programming!

Comment: If you are sure to run on Oracle JVMs, then you can afford it; if you are unsure, don't! (note: talking about the webservice, obviously)

Comment: If you doing this on Android there is a class for this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html. The main thing is it ties you to an Oracle VM which doesn't work for things like appengine. As an alternative there is a apache-commons-codec package.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, is useful! If you changes this classes for Apache Commons ,APPEngine can use it? I'm a bit newbie! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two questions here:

1) Use Base64 encoding? It increases load (a little) and length of the message (quite a lot). The advantage if that your content has simbols that do not mix well with SOAP (v.g. `< >`) as they get encoded they no longer cause trouble.

My recomendation? Use it for small pieces of information that may contain unsafe symbols (v.g. non sanitized Strings). If you have to pass large blobs of data (v.g. a file) try to do it with a more basic HTTP approach and not with SOAP/JSON.

2) Use that specific library? As fge states, it introduces a dependency on the VM. If you are sure to use Oracle JVMs you can, otherwise you can download a third party API and use it.

Comment: A lot, a lot... 33% is not that much for small messages. I'd rather be worried if neither end used content compression!

Comment: Thanks for developed answer! Do you know more basic HTTP methods to send a File (like Photo (~125KB)) to a Webservice? FTP maybe? Thank You!

Comment: For simplicity, I would stick to (plain) HTTP file transfer. FTP would be way too complicated.

Comment: @fge maybe I still feel the sequels of when we were trying to parse SOAP with attachments using DOM parsers, back in the day, but I still do not like the idea of B64 encoded files in SOAP.

Comment: Hypnotize, one option that I forgot to mention, multipart HTTP messages. It allows you to send a single HTTP message with several parts, the first part would be the SOAP messages and you can put the binary content in the others. Maybe it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it's not correct. Your program becomes non-portable because `sun.misc` package is not part of Java SE API and is not guaranteed to be present in the standard library.

2) You can use `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary` / `DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary` from `javax.xml.bind` package instead.